# What is the best way to search elements in a list with nested elements?

Tags: java, search

I have 2 classes:

```
public class ChatGroup{
    final public String name;
    private List<ChatContact> contacts;
    /* ---getters/setters/constructors-- */
}

public class ChatContact implements Parcelable, Comparable {
    final public String name;
    final public String jid;
    public Status status;
    /* ---getters/setters/constructors-- */
}
```

Then I have a list of ChatGroup items:

```
List<ChatGroup> chatGroupList = .....;
```

As you can see every ChatGroup has a list of ChatContact., and what I need is to search inside chatGroupsList, for ChatContacts that matches a query (search by username).

A way I'm doing, is do an auxilar list, search for every group, and look "inside" for ever chatContact, if exist I add the group with the contact:

```
private List<ChatGroup> searchContacts(String query) {
    List<ChatGroup> filteredContacts = new ArrayList<>();

    for (ChatGroup chatGroup : chatGroupList) {
        ChatGroup auxChatGroup = new ChatGroup(chatGroup.name);
        for (ChatContact chatContact : chatGroup.getContacts()) {
            if (chatContact.name.toLowerCase().contains(query)) {
                auxChatGroup.addContact(chatContact);
            }
        }
        if (auxChatGroup.getContacts().size() > 0)
            filteredContacts.add(auxChatGroup);
    }
    for (ChatGroup chatGroup : filteredContacts) {
        Collections.sort(chatGroup.getContacts());
    }
    return filteredContacts;
}
```

All of this works perfect. But right now, this list has few groups with few contacts each one, but in a future will be a high number of elements, and this could be a "slow" solution.

So my question is, there is another faster way to do this type of search?

Comment: Will you always search by `name` or do you also want to search by other properties as well?

Comment: always will be by name, because what I have is a view, with a expandable list, that shows as parents, every group, and as childs the contacts that belows to every group. And the user has to be able to serch in this list.

Comment: why are you doing a contains search with the name? are you seriously going to search for something like "a" and want everyone who has the letter A at any point in their name? that type of search does not index well.

Comment: yes.. I know is not a good way to search. Is better to search at the starting of the name, but, Boss wants in that way , so... :/  I'll try to convice him about it, but he's so close minded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you are seriously going to search for something like "a" and want everyone who has the letter A at any point in their name, that type of search does not index well.

But looking at your algorithm, I see a few possible improvements.

1. Initialize `ChatGroup auxChatGroup = null` and only create the object when you find a result that matches the filter. This will avoid creating a few unnecessary objects if you have lots of rooms.
2. Sorting the list of contacts every time you do a search seems like a lot of wasted effort. Using a sorted collection such as TreeSet could offer you a huge time savings on each search.
3. If the number of groups becomes huge, as in millions, then consider using a multi-threaded search.
4. Depending on your use case, it may be possible to return a filtered "view" instead of a snapshot. However that may add some complexity and possible gotchas.